# how to subset a specific column and the rows that go with that column in R

Tags: r, subset

In R, I want to subset from a column all the ones that have Brazil, Country is the variable, and all the rows associated with Brazil. I want more than just the column of Brazil, but I want Brazil to be what draws out what will be in my subset.

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: Or with `dplyr`: `df %>% filter(Cuntry == "Brazil")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Country` is a column in your dataframe and `some_df` is your dataframe

`some_df[some_df$Country == 'Brazil,]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in a R dataframe called DF.

```
subset(DF, Country == "Brazil")
```

does the trick. For future questions, read the guidelines how to write a question, you will get much more answers that way.

If you want to subset by more than one value for Country, use:

```
subset(DF, Country %in% c("Brazil", "Sweden", "Swaziland"))
```

type of construct.